# NoMethodError: Calling an instance method correctly in Ruby with the use of self

Tags: ruby, self, instance-methods

I was reading Why's (Poignant) guide to Ruby, and came across a method that didn't quite work out as expected. The method is aimed to return a value (from a hash) for a given string, somewhat like an encoder-decoder. Originally, the method was written inside a `class String`, but I modified it to change the classname. Here's the code:

```
class NameReplacer
  @@syllables = [

      {"Paij" => "Personal","Gonk" => "Business", "Blon" => "Slave", "Stro" => "Master", "Wert" => "Father", "Onnn" => "Mother"},
      {"ree" => "AM", "plo" => "PM"}
  ]

  # method to determine what a certain name of his means
  def name_significance
    # split string by -
    parts = self.split("-")
    # make duplicate of syllables
    syllables = @@syllables.dup
    signif = parts.collect {|name| syllables.shift[name]}
    #join array returned by " " forming a string
    signif.join(" ")
  end
end
```

To run this code, the book simply uses `"Paij-ree".name_significance`. But when I tried doing the same thing, I got a NoMethodError - `in <top (required)>: undefined method NameReplacer for "Paij-ree":String (NoMethodError)`.

I got the same error when I tried: `print "Paij-ree".NameReplacer.new.name_significance`

I assume this worked in the book because the method was written in a class `String`, which, I guess, would be equal to having this method in Ruby's `String` class. Due to that, something like `"paij-ree".name_significance"` would not throw an error, because the `"paij-ree"` would be a `String` object, and `String` class does have the method `name_significance`.

However, how do I accomplish this with my current code? Apologies if this question seems stupid.

Comment: The method being inside of `class String` is what allowed it to function. `String` is an existing Ruby class that you can add functionality to by "opening it" and adding new methods: e.g. declare a class called `String` (as the code was originally) and add new methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three approaches with same result:

```
# monkey-patching a class
class String
  def appendFoo
    self + "foo"
  end
end

"a".appendFoo
# => "afoo"

# using an external class method
class FooAppender
  def self.appendFoo(string)
    string + "foo"
  end
end

FooAppender.appendFoo("a")
# => "afoo"

# using an external instance method
class StuffAppender
  def initialize(what)
    @what = what
  end

  def append_to(string)
    string + @what
  end
end

new StuffAppender("foo").append_to("a")
# => "afoo"
```

`self` means the object the method is defined on. You can't use `self` in the `NameReplacer` class to refer to a string, it will be the `NameReplacer` instance (inside an instance method like yours).

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, that code depends on the String class. An alternative for you would be to extend the String class with your class like so:

```
class NameReplacer < String    
  @@syllables = [
    {
      "Paij" => "Personal",
      "Gonk" => "Business",
      "Blon" => "Slave",
      "Stro" => "Master",
      "Wert" => "Father",
      "Onnn" => "Mother"
    },
    {
      "ree" => "AM",
      "plo" => "PM"
    }
  ]

  # method to determine what a certain name of his means
  def name_significance
    # split string by -
    parts = self.split("-")
    # make duplicate of syllables
    syllables = @@syllables.dup
    signif = parts.collect {|name| syllables.shift[name]}
    #join array returned by " " forming a string
    signif.join(" ")
  end
end
```

And then use it like this:

```
p = NameReplacer.new("Paij-ree")
puts p.name_significance
```